# Quadratic Problem with 2 constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

Could someone help me to solve the following:

$\min x^Tx$

s.t.

$x^T a=1$

$x^T b=0$

where $x$,$a$ and $b$ are $(N\times1)$ vectors and $1$ and $0$ scalars.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stated problem is finding the minimum norm point in an underdetermined set of equations, see http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat419/lecture15.pdf

This problem is a special case of the least squares problem with equality constraints, see http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/l_ols_variants.html

Let me solve the problem:
Let $C = [a,b]^T$ and $c = [1,0]^T$ such that your problem becomes

$$\min_{x} \|x\|^2 ~~~~~{\rm s.t.    }~~~ Cx =c $$

then, the solution is given by

$x^\star = C^T(C C^T)^{-1}c$.

Comment: Great - thanks a lot for this! Any chance you could point me to some other more "readable" references on how this solution is calculated?

Comment: Dear mtm, see the edited post. If you are not happy with the reference, google "minimum norm point in an underdetermined set of equations". You'll find many good links. Plz vote up :-)

Comment: ... and accept!

Comment: Thanks again -accepted -  can't vote up just now as don't seem to have enough reputation :)